# Can execute permissions of a perl script be restricted to call from another perl script?

Tags: linux, perl, permissions

I have 2 perl scripts, one of them calls the other (system() call).  I do not want anything else to be able to execute that second perl script. Only the first perl script can run the second. The second perl script is a giant with lots of includes and forking and nested system calls of its own, so I'd like to avoid simply sticking it inside the first one as a subroutine (or anything like that).  However, it would be OK to wrap that second perl script inside a perl module/package or similar.  But the thing is I do not want any of the users of the first perl script to be able to execute the second perl script independently.

Is such a thing possible?
This is to be done on RHEL6.

I'm going to tag this with both perl and linux because I'm open to linux based solutions too.  And I'll tag with permissions because that's at the heart of what I'm talking about.  Note though that I do not have root.

Comment: Can you not include the second script inside the first with `use script2`?

Comment: If you make the second script a package, `use` that in the first script, and call the relevant methods, you should be fine. You can `chmod 0444` the second script (package). Aside from the fact that 'executing' the package would not do much.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this kind of restriction.

Comment: Whatever check you add could be removed anyway, so the best you can do is prevent accidental misuse. All you need for that is to have script 1 pass a "secret" value to script 2 as a an argument, and have script 2 check for it.

Comment: One unfortunate thing is that my users are perl savy.  So they too might simply use the perl module in a script of their own.
 
I thought of, and like, the idea of passing an access code from the first to the second.  But again, my perl savy users might just do the same thing if that passcode was in open text.  However, if it was encrypted somehow, maybe as an unreadable and uncopyable value which could be passed to the 2nd script, that might work.

Comment: Well, hang on.  Do these nosy users of yours have read access to the second script?  If they do, I don't see how you can prevent them from using it. If not, you can use a password.   Or you can write a wrapper that checks how it's called and abort unless it is called from the first script.  One can still get around that but it would have to be a very deliberate action.

Answer (score 2):

To guard against accidental misuse, you could simply check the parent process id and compare its command line execution to what you expect, something like the following, which uses `ps` to find that information.  But as long as the source code of your script is visible to other users, you can never truly prevent them from just copying/modifying it to suit their needs, so you may want to put a warning in the error message of *why* you think this is such a bad idea.

**script1.pl** and **some_other_script.pl** (both identical, with different names)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

(system('./script2.pl') == 0)
    or die "Unable to run script2.pl!";
```

**script2.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

chomp(my $ppid = `ps -o ppid= -p $$`);
chomp(my $parent_command = `ps -o command= $ppid`);

die "script2.pl must only be called from script1.pl!"
    unless $parent_command =~ m|perl\s+script1\.pl$|; # as suggested by @zdim

print "Have some pi : 3.14159\n";
```

**output**

```
$ perl script1.pl
Have some pi : 3.14159

$ perl script2.pl
script2.pl must only be called from script1.pl! at script2.pl line 9.

$ perl some_other_script.pl
script2.pl must only be called from script1.pl! at ./script2.pl line 9.
Unable to run script2.pl! at some_other_script.pl line 6.
```

Comment: This is the kind of a thing I do (for logging). But for this purpose it's beat by `stealing.pl script1.pl` -- where `stealing.pl` uses script1 _and_ submits it on the command line (and discards that argument).  Like you say, anything can be defeated if script is readable but we can still strengthen this, by say `/(perl\s+)?script1\.pl$/` (or so)

Comment: In fact, I think that `perl` _has to_ be there so one can drop `?` quantifier

Comment: Yeah, but you can get around that too, using something like argv0 : https://cr.yp.to/ucspi-tcp/argv0.html

Comment: Completely agree(d). (They can even just name it `script1` in some other directory.  I am not sure whether that can be beat with `ps` options, but even if it can the process can lie about the name reported by `ps`). I meant that this still can be done to help a little.

Comment: Thank You xxfelixxx and zdim.  That's ingenious and should do the trick.